# Nested DIVs - Prevent inner DIV from refresh

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I am currently refreshing a div as below.

**Main.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load_me').load('ajax.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
               //every 10000 milliseconds(10sec)
    </script>
```

However the page ajax.php has a number of DIV's that should not get refreshed. Is there a way to do this? That is, prevent specific DIV's from being refreshed at any cost (with their IDs).

The reason why this is required is, the DIV has text boxes which are getting refreshed when typing text.

Answer (score 1):

You could always select what elements to refresh, but doing the opposite and leaving elements out will be more complicated, especially if those elements are nested within elements that should be refreshed etc.

```
var to_refresh = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];

var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $.each(to_refresh, function(_,id) {
        $('#'+id).load('ajax.php #'+id).fadeIn("slow");
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you please explain further on how above method would prevent the inner div's from being refreshed? Say id1 has 3 inner divs. All of them are bound to be refreshed. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's why it is better to restructure your page such that you periodically refresh only those DIVs that don't have input elements inside.

Comment: You simply can't refresh an element like that, and expect children elements to not be refreshed. It's impossible! That's why you'd have a hell of a time trying to filter out elements to not refresh in content with lots of nesting, instead it would be easier to just target the elements that should be refreshed. All in all, you have a design flaw, you shouldn't have to do this at all, as you should have created the markup so that you didn't have to do any filtering at all, at least that's my opinion.